# How to remove previous items from ListBox, and add only the new ones?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a `C#` project using `SQLite` in Visual Studio that inserts some data in a `ListBox` through data binding. The problem is that if the table is changed and then the Page is loaded, the old values are still present i.e. I get old results and the new ones are appended.

How do remove the old values so that everytime I modify my selection I get only the new values?

```
List <NTable> l1 = dbConn.Query<NTable>("select * from NTable");
                    list1.ItemsSource = l1;
```

Next time when the page loads, `list1` should be empty so that only the retrieved rows can be displayed. Here retrieved rows along with previously retrieved rows, both are displayed on loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `ItemSource = null` , when you set the items on the next time,

```
  list1.ItemsSource = null;
  list1.ItemsSource = l1;
```

**Edit:**
      Clear the Items in List or create a new instance, when you get the data second time and bind to the list1, something like this,

```
 List <NTable> l1 = new List <NTable>();
 l1 = dbConn.Query<NTable>("select * from NTable");
 list1.ItemsSource = l1;
```

Comment: Tried this also...dosen't remove the old values..only adds the new values to the pevious items.

Comment: could you post your complete code? i think problem is not here.

Comment: Well actually the problem is with insertion of data into the table  that I am doing on another page. Actually, the table NTable has two  columns Employee and Votes. I want to insert values to NTable only when there is a new Employee.e.g. Emp7 and its votes value will be 1 first time. When  again someone votes Emp7, then no insertion should occure,only the count value should be increased to 2, but in my code Emp7 is also inserted alongwith count=2. Can you tell me how do I insert only when a new Employee is voted and update  votes column if existing employee is voted?